# Migrating SSRS reports and data driven subscriptions from 2008R2 to 2012

Tags: reporting-services

I was partially successful using rs.exe and ssrs_migration.rss:  https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/reporting-services/ssrs-migration-rss

But, the main problem is that the data driven subscriptions (or even a regular subscription) DID NOT get migrated along with the RDLs.  Also, the data source links were blank.

One wrinkle, maybe, is that my source is not on a domain (it is a standalone workgroup).

So my main question is:  has anybody successfully used ssrs_migration.rss to migrate data-driven subscriptions along with the RDLs?  If so, any advice to someone who constantly gets:  "migrating subscriptions for report ...  0 items found"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of testing, trying to tweak the code inside of ssrs_migration.rss -- I am convinced that it in fact DOES NOT migrate data driven subscriptions if the source is SP2010 and SQL Server 2012 and the target is SP2013 and SP Server 2012.  The code within ssrs_migration.rss that pulls out the data connection and data query for a data driven subscription are faulty in this context.